# Customise the virtualenv `activate` script

Tags: python, virtualenv, customization

What is the conventional way to customise the changes made by a Python virtualenv `bin/activate` script?

The Python virtualenv is activated by [a `$VENV/bin/activate` script](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/#activate). This script works primarily by setting environment variables specific to the virtualenv.

(This is different from the “bootstrap script” [discussed in the Virtualenv documentation](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/#creating-your-own-bootstrap-scripts). Those are used once, when creating the virtualenv; they are not used when activating the virtualenv. This question is about the activate script.)

Many of the code bases for which I use a Python virtualenv, need additional (custom) environment variables set, at the same time the virtualenv is activated.

- Edit the `$VENV/bin/activate` script directly, to add statements that set more environment variables?
- Write a custom wrapper script, that incidentally calls `$VENV/bin/activate`?
- Write a separate script with a specific name, that will be automatically called by the `$VENV/bin/activate` script? Does such a thing exist?

Of course I could write a script with a different name, and instruct developers to run that instead. Or I could instruct them to install `virtualenvwrapper`. But that is not the if-you-got-the-virtualenv-working-then-this-works-too automation that I'm seeking.

Instead, this question is asking how to hook into the *existing* convention, of activating the virtualenv with a known name `$VENV/bin/activate`.

Comment: There's documentation on this in the standard `venv` module docs. Chances are you're better off not coupling your particular setup and initialization needs to something as specific as venv.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)'s [pre-activate](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins.html#plugins-pre-activate) and [post-activate](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins.html#plugins-post-activate)
 hooks and [autoenv](https://github.com/kennethreitz/autoenv).

Answer (score 1):

How about using `virtualenvwrapper` and editing `$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/postactivate`?
http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts.html#scripts-postactivate